# remove words using regular expression

Tags: r, regex, nlp, gsub

I am trying to create a function that takes a tweet and process it for sentiment analysis.

```
tweet <- "Here’s a list of all of the exchanges #safemoon is affiliated with going into the AMAs today!\nIf you look at the roadmap- \nthey are planning to add more!\nWe’re still early and JUST getting started!\nCredit to @_tokendad \n#safemooncommunity #safemoonarmy #crypto #cryptotwitter"
```

I want to remove all hyperlinks, words that are hashtags (starting with #) and mentions (starting with @)

I solved the removing hyperlink function. How can I use regular expression to look for hashtags and mentions and remove them from tweet

```
process_tweet(tweet){

   tweet <- gsub('http\\S+', '', tweet) # get rid of hyperlinks
   tweet <- gsub(, '', tweet) # how do I look for words that start with @ or # and remove them

   return(tweet)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -

```
trimws(gsub('http\\S+|#\\w+|@\\w+', '', tweet))
```

This removes hyperlinks (`http\\S+`), hashtags (`#\\w+`) and mentions (`@\\w+`).